# getting each category from JSON data

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have JSON data, and am interested in the main category for each group within the array. Looks more or less like this:

```
var categoryData = {
            sun: { info },
            mon: { info },
            tue: { info },
            wed: { info },
            thu: { info },
            fri: { info },
            sat: { info }
        };
```

I'm trying to use .each() to iterate through and just grab these days of the week and put them each a list item. Here's the code I have for this:

```
// Load the categories into the navbar from the JSON data
        $(categoryData).each(function(index) {
            $('#custom-navbar').append('<li><a href="">' + this + '</a></li>');
        });
```

I run this code in my page (and with other working code) and instead of 7 days of the week I get "[object Object]". Then, once I navigate to another page (of the same multi-page doc) and then press the back button, there are 4 more of these [object Object] things.

Any ideas on this stuff?
Full code can be seen [here](http://www.triadbarspecials.com/app) (view page source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the loop, `this` refers to `info`, which in your code is likely another object (I did not look at your site code). You could try the following to get something that will be more predictable:

```
$(categoryData).each(function(key, val) {
   $('#custom-navbar').append('<li><a href="">' + key + '</a></li>');
});
```

Use `val` to get to particular properties of the `info` object.